# Orchard CMS: How to add version to theme scripts and styles

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I want to automaticaly add version parameter to all my theme scripts and styles, to get something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/themes/mytheme/Styles/common.min.css?v=12345"></script>
```

Are there some ways to do it by Orchard CMS?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Combinator module](https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Piedone.Combinator) on the Orchard gallery.

It will fingerprint your resources, as well as combining and minifying them if you want (all configured in the admin interface)